# Solve the equation via the substitution $x(t)=t y(t)$ $2 t x \frac{d x}{d t}-x^2=t^2, \quad t>0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the equation via the substitution $x(t)=t y(t)$ $$2 t x \frac{d x}{d t}-x^2=t^2, \quad t>0$$.
I know that this can be solved using Bernoulli's method. I have done the following according to the substitution given, but the correct result given is $x(t)^2=t(t+C)$.
Could someone please tell me where did I do wrong in the calculation, thank you in advance!

\begin{aligned}
&2 t x x^{\prime}-x^2=t^2 \\
&\frac{x(t)}{t}=y(t) \\
&\frac{d x}{d t}=y(t)+t y^{\prime}(t)=\frac{t^2+x^2}{2 t x}=\frac{1}{2} y+\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{y} \\
&y^{\prime}(t)=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{y}-y\right) \frac{1}{2}}{t} \\
&\int \frac{2 y}{1-y^2} d y=\int \frac{1}{t} d t \\
&-I n| 1-y^2|=I n| t \mid+c \\
&\frac{1}{1-y^2}=t+c, t>0 \\
&\frac{1}{\mid-\frac{x^2}{t^2}}=t+c \\
&\frac{t^2}{t^2-x^2}=t+c \\
&t^2=t^3+t^2 c-t x^2-\left(x^2\right. \\
&(t+c) x^2=t^2(t-1-c) \\
&x^2=\frac{t^2(t-1-c)}{t+c}
\end{aligned}

Comment: $-\ln |1 - y^2| = \ln |t| + c \Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{|1 - y^2|} = |t| e^c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is not correct:
$$\dfrac{1}{1-y^2}=t+c$$
It should be :
$$\dfrac{1}{1-y^2}=Ct$$
Because:
$$e^{\ln t +c}=e^ce^{\ln t}=e^ct=Ct$$
Note that the DE is simply:
$$2 t x \frac{d x}{d t}-x^2=t^2$$
$$ t  \frac{d x^2}{d t}-x^2=t^2$$
$$\left (  \dfrac {x^2}{ t}\right)'=1\;\; (t>0)$$
That you can easily integrate.

---

You have to consider three  cases
$$y= \pm1 \implies x=\pm t$$
Second case $1-y^2 >0$ you treated this case in your attempt. You find that;
$$x^2=t\left (t-\dfrac 1 {e^c}\right)=t\left (t-A\right) \;\; (A>0)$$
Then the third case when $1-y^2 <0$ then:
$$-\ln |1-y^2|=c+\ln t  \;\; (t>0)$$
$$\dfrac 1 {y^2-1}=e^ct$$
$$\dfrac {t^2}{x^2-t^2}=e^ct$$
$$x^2=\dfrac t {e^c}+t^2$$
$$x^2=t\left (t+\dfrac 1 {e^c}\right)$$
$$x^2=t\left (t+A\right) \,\, A>0$$
This summarize the three cases:
$$x^2=t\left (t+C\right) \,\, C \in \mathbb {R}$$

Comment: thanks for pointing out the simple mistake I made :D. I have another question, you wrote $e^c=C$, I mean $e^c$ is never negative, then you mean $C$ must be larger than $0$ right?

Comment: Yes true but you cant have also $y=1$ because the log of $y-1$ dosent exist too this is the problem with the method used here  to integrate this DE. With integrating factor you have less problems to deal with  ....@RuoLinWang

Comment: When $y= \pm 1$ the log make no sense but the solution $y=\pm 1 \implies x=\pm t$ is a solution of the original DE. You have to be very carefull with the log  function @RuoLinWang

Comment: I completed my answer I hope this is now mire clear @RuoLinWang

Comment: thank you, really appreciated !

Comment: You''re welcome @RuoLinWang